# How to share mutex between main thread and library callback?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a situation where I have a main thread in which I am sending some data to an external service(using the service's write queue) every 10 seconds.

I have also registered a callback with an dbus library which can trigger at random time. When the callback triggers, I want to send it's data to the same external service (from within the callback fucntion) using the same write queue used in my main thread. (the handling of the callback is done in a separate thread.

What is the best way to share a mutex between main thread and library callback?

Comment: How do you share the callback itself? E.g. if it is a lambda, you could simply capture the mutex. Or is there perhaps a `void*` parameter for user-data?

Comment: Yes I can pass any parameter to the callback. Pointer to mutex will be a good idea in this case?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual code, or at least documentation for the dbus library.  But yes, a pointer to a mutex will work, provided you can pass that pointer into the callback. Otherwise, worse case, you could just put the mutex into global memory

Comment: If you know the mutex will outlive the callback, I think so. If you want to be extra careful, `std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>` would prevent dangling pointers, but IMHO it's better to have a clear owner.

Comment: `shared_ptr` might be more difficult to use if the dbus library is designed with a C-style callback interface that can't pass around C++ smart pointers

Comment: Yes, probably, as you said the actual code would be nice.

Comment: The calling function will outlive anything and the mutex will not go anywhere. I am thinking of using std::make_unique<std::mutex>() and then using the resulting ptr in both places. Thoughts?